# confused xtics scale appearing when bold xtics in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I met a problem when adding code`set xtics format "{/:Bold %.0s}"` to bold xtics.The code and results were listed below.If I comment on the code `set xtics format "{/:Bold %.0s}"`, it appears normal but without bolding xtics what I expected. How can I fix it? I will appreciate it for any suggestions!

```
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d%H"
set format x "%m/%d"
set xrange ["20200106":"20200228"]
set xtics nomirror format '{/:Bold %.0s}'
set xtics("20200106","20200115","20200124","20200202","20200211","20200220", "20200228") font "Times, 11"
set ytics nomirror font "Times,11"
set ytics format "{/:Bold %.0s}"
set ytics 0,80,400
set datafile missing "-999"
unset key
set origin 0, 0.80
unset ylabel
```

[image: map]

Answer (score 1):

You set a xtic format "%s", which is interpreted as time in seconds.  That is clearly not what you want.  If the idea is that the xtics have the same format as you set for timefmt, then you could use

```
set xtics nomirror format '{/:Bold %Y%m%d%H}'
```

or better

```
set xtics nomirror format'%Y%m%d%H'
set xtics font ':Bold'
```

or if the idea is to use specifically the labels you put in a `set xtics (T1,T2,T3)` command then the trick is to realize that if you give only a single value in Tx it is used as a location, not a label string.  The label for this position is generated by using the tic format.   If you give *two* values for Tx then the first one is a fixed label text and the second one is the position.  If I understand your intent correctly, you want the label string to be the same as the position; that means your list of labels would become:

```
set xtics("20200106" "20200106","20200115" "20200115","20200124" "20200124","20200202" "20200202","20200211" "20200211","20200220" "20200220", "20200228" "20200228)
```

If you do that, it doesn't matter what the xtic format is because it will just use the string provided.

Comment: Your advice is really helpful. I use this method `set xtics("{/:Bold 01/06} 20200106"……)` to make it. I try your method, but it couldn't work.

Comment: Hello, there is another question. How to add mxtics in this map. I try to use `set mxtics 100`, but the scale is too dense to read.

Comment: Instead of putting Bold in the format, use a bold font (see amended answer). So `set xtics font":Bold,15"; set xtics ("20200106" "20200106", ...)`